# Header image from media field with default image as fallback

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want to add a dynamic header image from the media field to each site of my project. I'm new to typoscript and i finally found a snippet which is working with Typo3 6.2:

```
lib.headerImg = FILES
lib.headerImg {
  references {
    table = pages
    uid.data = tsfe:id
    fieldName = media
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj.10 = IMAGE
    renderObj.10 {
    file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
    altText.data = file:current:title
  }
  begin = 0
  maxItems = 1
}
```

I'd like to have a default image diplayed if the current site has no media field set. How do I do that?
I guess there's a simple solution for that but I have absolutely no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it work like

```
10 = IMAGE
10 {
 file = fileadmin/upload/default.jpg
 #file.maxH = 175
 #file.maxW = 280
 file.import=uploads/media/ 
 file.import.data = levelmedia: -1,slide
 file.import.listNum = 0
 file.import.override.field = media
 titleText.field = title
 altText.field = title
 file.import.listNum=0
}
```

In you case must be:

```
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj.10 = IMAGE
    renderObj.10 {
    file = fileadmin/upload/default.jpg
    file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
    altText.data = file:current:title
  }
```

So if data empty you take default image. *There are one more way Like:*

```
#...
ifEmpty.data = levelmedia: -2,slide 
#...
```

This case give you  image from parent page, but I'm not sure how to modify your code. So ude first example, second just for fun)